# Drupal 7 Default .htaccess

Tags: drupal, .htaccess, drupal-7

I am after the default .htaccess code for Drupal 7, for some reason the install did not update the .htaccess file at all and it is blank.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I can't find this anywhere.

Comment: Have you considered asking it on http://drupal.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Thanks Oscar, I didn't think of that (but I got my answer here anyways).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Actually, the official Drupal source code is on GitHub: https://github.com/drupal/drupal.
The requested .htaccess file can be found [here](https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/7.x/.htaccess).

Comment: Thanks mate. For anyone new reading this post, this is probably the more accurate answer now.

Comment: This is actually a mirror of the official code. The .htaccess from the official 7.x repository is here: https://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/.htaccess?h=7.x