# .htaccess default directory behaviour

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have just started learning about .htaccess files for Apache, I have a website set up so that all requests should come through my index file (which is called Main.php).

"Webpages" are then acquired through a wp GET var (such as wp=forum) - i wish to make this instead `Domain/directory/Forum` instead of the current `Doman/directory/Main.php?wp=Forum`

The problem i am facing is that all my "webpages" are stored in their own directory and are made up of "webparts" so forum will be a sub directory of "forum" with files inside it that make up the page. This is causing problems with my redirecting.

I have created the following .htacess file:

```
#turn redirect engine on
RewriteEngine On
#make sure URI is not a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^?]*)$ Main.php?wp=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

This works fine on the redirecting until it is a directory that is entered as the "wp" at which time it will add a trailing slash and corrupt the wp GET var passed (forum/ would be passed not forum as needed)

Here are 2 examples of how I think it may be working:

**Main (not a file or directory)**

- loop 1: Hits the rewrite  changes to Main.php?wp=Main
- loop 2: URI is file (no change)

**MainContent (is a directory)**

- loop 1: Hits the default directory change? (guess) Changes to
  MainContent/ (note the trailing slash)
- loop 2: Starts .htaccess and changes this to Main.php?wp=MainContent/
- loop 3: URI is file (no change)

Moreover, whenever a file is accessed in my websever with a trailing slash after to (so example: Main.php/) it will display with no links or included files. It will just show the file being requested and seems to ignore any and all css ... php includes or anything else (is this default Apache settings?).

Sorry for the long and possible confusing post. If I need to clean anything up just shout.

Comment: How about in your Main.php file triming the Request URI to remove the /

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with that:

```
#turn redirect engine on
RewriteEngine On
DirectorySlash Off
#make sure URI is not a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ Main.php?wp=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Literally beaten to this by a whisker.

Comment: Worked like a charm! - Could u aslo example the last part of my question or should it be in a new post?

Comment: You can do it here, but I did not catch what still does not work

Comment: yer sorry, it is hard to example as i'm not really sure what i'm asking. Lets try again: so when i add a "/" to any end of a file (such as main.php/) it will display Main.php but css ... javascript ... anything else related to the file other than the base php and html in THAT file are removed. Any idea why?

Comment: Avoid to do that :-) But you can use absolute link or `<base href="http://www.example.com/">` in your html. I add / in the rule to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful to look at the .htaccess file for Drupal, which does the same thing - i.e. redirect all requests through the index file.  The most relevant snippet from that file is:

```
  # Pass all requests not referring directly to files in the filesystem to index.php?page=[rest of url]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The second condition above "! -d" might solve the problem you describe but you might still need to do some "cleaning" in your php code.  It's worth looking at the whole Drupal .htaccess file as it does other things to tighten security, such as blocking access to certain files etc.

Comment: Do you have a pastebin or something of the full .htaccess of Drupal? I'm very interested in seeing it without downloading the whole script.

Comment: This post has a link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864861/drupal-7-default-htaccess

Comment: unless i am mistaken (which nooby as I am I might be) this would not work due to the RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d as the requested URI IS a directory and therefore would just hit a 403 or the directory listing, if not disabled.